# Reducer can't receive data from action creators

Tags: redux, react-redux

I've got a problem with my reducer. I have created an action creator, reducer, and used 'react-redux' connect to combine both.

When I'm fireing my action, action creator logs, that he just received a new data, but reducer does not log anything (Reducer logs only 3 initial loops). Also, store.getState() which I'm display in console every 5 seconds shows null (which is initial state of my store). Could you help me to deal with the problem?

```
export const UPDATE_PACKAGE_JSON = 'UPDATE_PACKAGE_JSON';

export function setName(name){
  console.log('Action creator just received a name', name);
  return {
    type: UPDATE_PACKAGE_JSON,
    payload: name
  }
}
```

Container

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>
  bindActionCreators({ setName }, dispatch);

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ConfigurationForm) ;
```

Reducer

```
import { UPDATE_PACKAGE_JSON } from './../actions/index';

export const packageJson = function (state = null, action){
  console.log(UPDATE_PACKAGE_JSON);
  switch(action.type){
    case UPDATE_PACKAGE_JSON:
    return {...state,
      name: action.payload};
  }
  return state;
};
```

EDIT

Store

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';

import rootReducer from './../reducers/rootReducer';

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

export default store;
```

rootReducer

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import { packageJson } from './packageJson';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  packageJson
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: Are you sure your initial state shouldn't be `{}`?

Comment: I just changed it, but it didn't changed main problem: my reducer isn't fired at all, so it can't change my store state :(

Comment: Can you post your store file as well? The store setup is where you point Redux to your reducers. Sounds like Redux may not know your packageJson reducer exists right now?

Comment: Here you are m8